# jsf - ajax javascript call not working due to a <h:form>

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, xhtml, facelets

**Problem:**

I have a button with an action and an ajax call to a js function but the javascript function is not executed. But when I remove the `<h:form>` it will work perfectly. Anybody has an idea why this happens, and how to fix it?

I would really like to use a form.

**Code:**

Working:

```
                <h:commandButton id="dice" alt="W&uuml;rfel" image="resources/img/wuerfel0.png" action="#{spiel.dice()}" tabindex="4" title="W&uuml;rfel">
                    <f:ajax render="gameinfo" onevent="animate" />
                </h:commandButton>
```

Not working:

```
         <h:form>
                <h:commandButton id="dice" alt="W&uuml;rfel" image="resources/img/wuerfel0.png" action="#{spiel.dice()}" tabindex="4" title="W&uuml;rfel">
                    <f:ajax render=":gameinfo" onevent="animate" />
                </h:commandButton>
         </h:form>
```

I also tried to realize it with a commandLink, same problem!

Comment: Are you using template / ui:include ? when you adding the  `<h:form> ` and doing view source in your generated page , are you seeing multiple `form` tags ?

Comment: I am using include but only for the header and footer. No multiple `form`tags in source code.

Comment: try setting your `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` into `Development` in your web.xml and look at the server logs / browser console... also try using a newer mojarra / myfaces jars

Comment: Hmm... If you're using mojarra then it shouldn't work without a form element (see [here](https://www.java.net//node/697614) or in the documentation of jsf.ajax.request javascript function). Are you 100% sure that in the generated HTML there are no `form` tags?

Comment: There is a form in a different section of the code. But the button is defenitly in no form. The ajax render as well as the javascript call works fine.

Comment: if you remove the form that you mentioned in your question , and run your web app and do view source on your generated page you see `input` with id `dice` or `someFormID:dice` in your code that is a child / distant child of some `form` in your page , try to inspect it better..,

Comment: `<div id="player" class="player">
                        <h2 class="accessibility">Würfelbereich</h2>
                        <span class="accessibility">An der Reihe ist</span><div id="currentPlayerName"> Jakob</div><input id="dice" type="image" src="resources/img/wuerfel0.png" name="dice" alt="Würfel" tabindex="4" title="Würfel" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'gameinfo',{'onevent':animate});return false" /></div>
                </div>`
This is the generated source, as you can see the id="dice" its no child of any form

Comment: And that `<div id="player"` got no `form` somewhere above him (parent)... strange...